# NEProviderTargetTemplates in macOS Sierra

Tags: ios, macos-sierra, networkextension

In macOS Sierra this file don't exists.

Reported bug to apple number  28697094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can get them, from NetworkExtension.framework of El Capitan version.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9w4ga1jdomyvsnj/NetworkExtension.framework.zip?dl=0